# How to use search bar component to filter card component results. ReactJS, NextJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have a search bar component Search.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
export default function Search() {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"></link>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inter" />
            
            <form className={styles.search_bar} action="">
            <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. Adobo" onChange={event => setQuery(event.target.value)} />
            <button><i className="material-icons">search</i></button>
            </form>
      </div>
    )
}
```

and I want to filter the results that show up in my Card.jsx

```
import styles from "./Card.module.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Card() {
    const [menus, setMenus] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/63863ca77966e84526cf79f9")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setMenus(data)
        })
      }, [])
    

    return (
        <div className= {styles.card_container}>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inter" />
                {menus.record?.map( menu => (  
                    <div className={styles.container}>
                        <div key ={menu.title} className={styles.img_container}> 
                        <img className={styles.card_img} src={menu.image} alt="Food Image"/>
                        </div>
                        <h1 className={styles.card_title}>{menu.title}</h1>
                        <h1 className={styles.card_body}>
                        {menu.body}
                        </h1>
                        <h1 className={styles.card_price}>{menu.price}</h1>
                        <button className={styles.card_button}> Add to Order </button>
                    </div>          
                ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I tried using the filter method but I really don't know how to implement it between two components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to access `query` inside the `Card` component so that you can filter the list of items.

You can achieve this by lifting the `query` state inside a parent component and passing `query` and `setQuery` as props, like so:

```
function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')

  return (
    <div>
      <Card query={query} />
      <Search query={query} setQuery={setQuery} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now your `Search` component uses these props instead of its own state:

```js
function Search({ query, setQuery }) {
```

And your `Card` component, too:

```js
function Card({ query }) {
  ...
  {menus.record?.filter(el => /* some filtering with query */).map
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much. I am new to react and passing props are a new concept to me. Thank you again for answering <3

Answer (score 0):

1. Add context for your orders, because the Search and Card components are not nested so you can't pass your data between them.
2. Add onClick function to your search button.
3. Do the filter in onClick.
4. Update the context value based on the search result.
5. Use the updated context value to render your menus.

As a sample code:

Context

```js
export const CardContext = React.createContext();
export function CardProvider({ children }) {
  const [menus, setMenus] = useState([]);

  return (
    <CardContext.Provider value={{menus, setMenus}}>
      { children }
    </CardContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Card component

```js
const { menus, setMenus } = useContext(CardContext);
```

Search Component

```js
const { menus, setMenus } = useContext(CardContext);

const handleSearch = () => {
  let newMenus = [...menus];
  newMenus.record = newMenus.record.filter((menuRecord) => menuRecord.title.includes(query));
  setMenus(newMenus);
}
```

```js
<button onClick={handleSearch}><i className="material-icons">search</i></button>
```